# watchkit developer library allows to access microphone?

Tags: watchkit, microphone

Regarding to new API release for watchkit on WWDC 2015, I am wondering

- if watchkit library allows a developer to access audio data coming from microphone on apple watch?
- if we can control the gain of microphone on apple watch?
- if we can enable/disable AGC (automatic gain control) for microphone on apple watch?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may record audio using watchOS 2.0. Sample code provided by Apple is available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/samplecode/WatchKitAudioRecorder/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016225).